# Successful .ajax() POST doesn't pass variables to PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I know this question has been posted already, but I'm not seeing anything that will help solve my problem.

Trying to post form data and then in PHP using mysqli, update a SQL table with the data. The POST is successful and returns code 200. For some reason (I'm assuming a timing issue, but unsure) the PHP variables are always undefined. I don't get any errors, but I can see that the PHP variables are undefined from the response.

I'm deploying by going to display_employee.php. It displays a dropdown list of employee names. An employee can be selected and their information can be edited.

emp_edit.php:

```
<?php
include '../part1/DBConnection.php';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if (!($result = $conn->prepare("UPDATE employees SET emp_firstName=?, emp_lastName=?, emp_middleName=?, emp_type=?, emp_initialLevel=?, emp_hireDate=?, emp_gender=?, emp_birthDate=?, emp_passwd=? WHERE emp_id=?"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $result->errno . ") " . $result->error;
  }

 if (!$result->bind_param("isssssssss", $emp_id, $emp_firstName, $emp_lastName, $emp_middleName, $emp_type, $emp_initialLevel, $emp_hireDate, $emp_gender, $emp_birthDate, $emp_passwd)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $result->errno . ") " . $result->error;
      }


  // populate param vars
  if (isset($_POST['emp_id_edit'])) {
    $emp_id = $_POST['emp_id_edit'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_firstName_edit'])) {
    $emp_firstName = $_POST['emp_firstName_edit'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_lastName_edit'])) {
    $emp_lastName = $_POST['emp_lastName_edit'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_middleName_edit'])) {
    $emp_middleName = $_POST['emp_middleName_edit'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_type_edit'])) {
    $emp_type = $_POST['emp_type_edit'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_initialLevel_edit'])) {
    $emp_initialLevel = $_POST['emp_initialLevel_edit'];
  }  
  if (isset($_POST['emp_hireDate_edit'])) {
    $emp_hireDate = $_POST['emp_hireDate_edit'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_gender_edit'])) {
    $emp_gender = $_POST['emp_gender_edit'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_birthDate_edit'])) {
    $emp_birthDate = $_POST['emp_birthDate_edit'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_passwd_edit'])) {
    $emp_passwd = $_POST['emp_passwd_edit'];
  }

  if (!$result->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $result->errno . ") " . $result->error;
  }
  else if($result->execute()) {
    echo "result: " . $emp_id;
  }
  $conn->close();
}
```

display_employee.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../part1/DBConnection.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="drop_list">
    <p> Choose an employee </p>
  </div>

  <div id="button_container">
    <button id="emp_edit">Edit Data</button>
    <button id="emp_add">>Add Employee</button>
    <div id="input_fields"></div>

</body>    
</html>
```

ajaxfile.php:

```
<?php
include "../part1/DBConnection.php";
$return_arr = array();
$query = "SELECT emp_id, emp_firstName, emp_lastName FROM employees ORDER BY emp_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $emp_id = $row['emp_id'];
    $emp_firstName = $row['emp_firstName'];
    $emp_lastName = $row['emp_lastName'];

    $return_arr[] = array(
        "emp_id" => $emp_id,
        "emp_firstName" => $emp_firstName,
        "emp_lastName" => $emp_lastName

    );
}
// Encoding array in JSON format
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

The jQuery Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxfile.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            var len = response.length;
            var output = "<select id = 'selection'>"
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var emp_id = response[i].emp_id;
                var emp_firstName = response[i].emp_firstName;
                var emp_lastName = response[i].emp_lastName;
                output += "<option value='" + emp_id + "' name='" + emp_id + "'>" + emp_id + " " + emp_firstName + " " + emp_lastName + "</option>";
            }
            $("#drop_list").append(output);
            $("#drop_list").append("</select>");
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#emp_add').on('click', function () {
        $("#emp_edit").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#emp_add").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#input_fields").empty();
        var input_fields = "<form id='emp_add_form' name='form1' method='post'><label for='emp_firstName_add'>First Name</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_firstName_add' name='emp_firstName_add'></br><label for='emp_middleName_add'>Middle Name</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_middleName_add' name='emp_middleName_add'></br><label for='emp_lastName_add'>Last Name</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_lastName_add' name='emp_lastName_add'></br><label for='emp_type_add'>Type</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_type_add' name='emp_type_add'></br><label for='emp_initialLevel_add'>Initial Level</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_initialLevel_add' name='emp_initialLevel_add'></br><label for='emp_hireDate_add'>Hire Date</label><input type='date' class='input_fields' id='emp_hireDate_add' name='emp_hireDate_add'></br><label for='emp_gender_add'>Gender</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_gender_add' name='emp_gender_add'></br><label for='emp_birthDate_add'>Birth Date</label><input type='date' class='input_fields' id='emp_birthDate_add' name='emp_birthDate_add'></br><label for='emp_passwd_add'>Password</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_passwd_add' name='emp_passwd_add'></br><input type='button' name='add_btn' value='Add to database' id='add_btn'></form>"
        $("#input_fields").append(input_fields);

        $('#add_btn').on('click', function (e) {
            var emp_firstName = $('#emp_firstName_add').val();
            var emp_lastName = $('#emp_lastName_add').val();
            var emp_middleName = $('#emp_middleName_add').val();
            var emp_type = $('#emp_type_add').val();
            var emp_initialLevel = $('#emp_initialLevel_add').val();
            var emp_hireDate = $('#emp_hireDate_add').val();
            var emp_gender = $('#emp_gender_add').val();
            var emp_birthDate = $('#emp_birthDate_add').val();
            var emp_passwd = $('#emp_passwd_add').val();

            if (emp_firstName != "" && emp_lastName != "" && emp_initialLevel != "" && emp_hireDate != "" && emp_gender != "" && emp_birthDate != "") {
                e.preventDefault()
                $.ajax({
                    url: "emp_add.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        emp_firstName: emp_firstName,
                        emp_lastName: emp_lastName,
                        emp_middleName: emp_middleName,
                        emp_type: emp_type,
                        emp_initialLevel: emp_initialLevel,
                        emp_hireDate: emp_hireDate,
                        emp_gender: emp_gender,
                        emp_birthDate: emp_birthDate,
                        emp_passwd: emp_passwd
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (dataResult) {
                        $("#emp_add").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#input_fields").empty();
                        $('#input_fields').append('<p>Data added successfully !</p>');
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Please fill all the required fields !');
            }
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#emp_edit').on('click', function () {
        $("#emp_add").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#emp_edit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#input_fields").empty();
        var input_fields = "<form id='emp_edit_form' name='form2' method='post'><label for='emp_id_edit'>ID</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_id_edit' name='emp_id_edit' value=" + $('#selection').val() + " readonly></br><label for='emp_firstName_edit'>First Name</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_firstName_edit' name='emp_firstName_edit'></br><label for='emp_middleName_edit'>Middle Name</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_middleName_edit' name='emp_middleName_edit'></br><label for='emp_lastName_edit'>Last Name</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_lastName_edit' name='emp_lastName_edit'></br><label for='emp_type_edit'>Type</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_type_edit' name='emp_type_edit'></br><label for='emp_initialLevel_edit'>Initial Level</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_initialLevel_edit' name='emp_initialLevel_edit'></br><label for='emp_hireDate_edit'>Hire Date</label><input type='date' class='input_fields' id='emp_hireDate_edit' name='emp_hireDate_edit'></br><label for='emp_gender_edit'>Gender</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_gender_edit' name='emp_gender_edit'></br><label for='emp_birthDate_edit'>Birth Date</label><input type='date' class='input_fields' id='emp_birthDate_edit' name='emp_birthDate_edit'></br><label for='emp_passwd_edit'>Password</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_passwd_edit' name='emp_passwd_edit'></br><input type='submit' name='edit_btn' value='Edit Data' id='edit_btn'></form>"
        $("#input_fields").append(input_fields);

        $('#edit_btn').on('click', function (e) {
            var emp_id = $("#selection").val();
            var emp_firstName = $('#emp_firstName_edit').val();
            var emp_lastName = $('#emp_lastName_edit').val();
            var emp_middleName = $('#emp_middleName_edit').val();
            var emp_type = $('#emp_type_edit').val();
            var emp_initialLevel = $('#emp_initialLevel_edit').val();
            var emp_hireDate = $('#emp_hireDate_edit').val();
            var emp_gender = $('#emp_gender_edit').val();
            var emp_birthDate = $('#emp_birthDate_edit').val();
            var emp_passwd = $('#emp_passwd_edit').val();

            if (emp_firstName != "" && emp_lastName != "" && emp_initialLevel != "" && emp_hireDate != "" && emp_gender != "" && emp_birthDate != "") {
                e.preventDefault()
                $.ajax({
                    url: "emp_edit.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        emp_firstName: emp_firstName,
                        emp_lastName: emp_lastName,
                        emp_middleName: emp_middleName,
                        emp_type: emp_type,
                        emp_initialLevel: emp_initialLevel,
                        emp_hireDate: emp_hireDate,
                        emp_gender: emp_gender,
                        emp_birthDate: emp_birthDate,
                        emp_passwd: emp_passwd
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function () {
                        $("#emp_edit").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#input_fields").empty();
                        $("#selection option:selected").text(emp_id + " " + emp_firstName + " " + emp_lastName);
                        $('#input_fields').append('<p>Data edited successfully!</p>');
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Please fill all the required fields !');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Request Header:

```
POST /group12_project/part2/emp_edit.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 167
Origin: http://localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost/group12_project/part2/display_employee.php
Cookie: PHPSESSID=n5tds5287ctojoils5r6h21blb
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 12 Mar 2021 19:15:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 8
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Here's the request payload:

```
emp_id=1&emp_firstName=123&emp_lastName=123&emp_middleName=123&emp_type=23&emp_initialLevel=123&emp_hireDate=2021-03-12&emp_gender=123&emp_birthDate=2021-03-09&emp_passwd=23
```

The response body should result in the values of ID and Password entered in the form. These are empty, no error saying the variable is undefined. Let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will want to review your POST Payload in the browser to see if the values are coming through as expected. I would then suggest using `var_export($_POST)` in your PHP as a test to see what PHP is getting.

Comment: Indeed, open your browser dev tool and lookup the request-response. You've got the request headers, can you also see the request body containing the POST fields data? These should be there.

Comment: emp_firstName=123&emp_lastName=123&emp_middleName=123&emp_type=1&emp_initialLevel=2&emp_hireDate=2021-03-10&emp_gender=123&emp_birthDate=2021-03-02&emp_passwd=123. This is the request payload, assuming that is what you mean. I will try that line in PHP as well.

Comment: The response payload should be:  "Result: [id]-[passwd]" But since the variables are empty I just get "result: -" (the vars defined but with no data in them)

Comment: `$("#drop_list").append("</select>");` is not necessary. You're appending DOM elements, not concatenating HTML.

Comment: The select needs a closing tag, though?

Comment: The DOM is a tree of elements. There's no closing tags in the DOM, just a select element with options as children. You're confusing the DOM with HTML.

Comment: Ohh, okay. So I can just remove that line then? Or do I need to modify it somehow

Comment: You could use `output += '</select>'` if you want, but jQuery will automatically close the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your request params which you put in the comments:
`emp_firstName=123&emp_lastName=123&emp_middleName=123&emp_type=1&emp_initialLevel=2&emp_hireDate=2021-03-10&emp_gender=123&emp_birthDate=2021-03-02&emp_passwd=123. This is the request payload, assuming that is what you mean. I will try that line in PHP as well. – bender_matt 11 mins ago`

I do not see `emp_id_edit` is set in the $_POST. That's why the code returns `result:`

I believe you might have missed sending it in the edit code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#emp_edit').on('click', function () {
        $("#emp_add").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#emp_edit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#input_fields").empty();
        var input_fields = "<form id='emp_edit_form' name='form2' method='post'><label for='emp_id_edit'>ID</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_id_edit' name='emp_id_edit' value=" + $('#selection').val() + " readonly></br><label for='emp_firstName_edit'>First Name</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_firstName_edit' name='emp_firstName_edit'></br><label for='emp_middleName_edit'>Middle Name</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_middleName_edit' name='emp_middleName_edit'></br><label for='emp_lastName_edit'>Last Name</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_lastName_edit' name='emp_lastName_edit'></br><label for='emp_type_edit'>Type</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_type_edit' name='emp_type_edit'></br><label for='emp_initialLevel_edit'>Initial Level</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_initialLevel_edit' name='emp_initialLevel_edit'></br><label for='emp_hireDate_edit'>Hire Date</label><input type='date' class='input_fields' id='emp_hireDate_edit' name='emp_hireDate_edit'></br><label for='emp_gender_edit'>Gender</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_gender_edit' name='emp_gender_edit'></br><label for='emp_birthDate_edit'>Birth Date</label><input type='date' class='input_fields' id='emp_birthDate_edit' name='emp_birthDate_edit'></br><label for='emp_passwd_edit'>Password</label><input type='text' class='input_fields' id='emp_passwd_edit' name='emp_passwd_edit'></br><input type='submit' name='edit_btn' value='Edit Data' id='edit_btn'></form>"
        $("#input_fields").append(input_fields);

        $('#edit_btn').on('click', function (e) {
            var emp_id = $("#selection").val();
            var emp_firstName = $('#emp_firstName_edit').val();
            var emp_lastName = $('#emp_lastName_edit').val();
            var emp_middleName = $('#emp_middleName_edit').val();
            var emp_type = $('#emp_type_edit').val();
            var emp_initialLevel = $('#emp_initialLevel_edit').val();
            var emp_hireDate = $('#emp_hireDate_edit').val();
            var emp_gender = $('#emp_gender_edit').val();
            var emp_birthDate = $('#emp_birthDate_edit').val();
            var emp_passwd = $('#emp_passwd_edit').val();

            if (emp_firstName != "" && emp_lastName != "" && emp_initialLevel != "" && emp_hireDate != "" && emp_gender != "" && emp_birthDate != "") {
                e.preventDefault()
                $.ajax({
                    url: "emp_edit.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        emp_id_edit: emp_id,
                        emp_firstName: emp_firstName,
                        emp_lastName: emp_lastName,
                        emp_middleName: emp_middleName,
                        emp_type: emp_type,
                        emp_initialLevel: emp_initialLevel,
                        emp_hireDate: emp_hireDate,
                        emp_gender: emp_gender,
                        emp_birthDate: emp_birthDate,
                        emp_passwd: emp_passwd
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function () {
                        $("#emp_edit").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#input_fields").empty();
                        $("#selection option:selected").text(emp_id + " " + emp_firstName + " " + emp_lastName);
                        $('#input_fields').append('<p>Data edited successfully!</p>');
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Please fill all the required fields !');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I get the same result after doing this.

Comment: Please update your code above then so we can take a look

Comment: `bind_param()` uses references, so it actually works before setting the variables.

Comment: That's what I thought too, @Barmar

Comment: You are correct it does use references, sorry for that. I'll keep looking

Comment: Good catch, didn't notice that

Comment: Even with that fixed, the variable is still undefined.

Comment: The new request payload: emp_id=1&emp_firstName=123&emp_lastName=123&emp_middleName=123&emp_type=23&emp_initialLevel=123&emp_hireDate=2021-03-12&emp_gender=123&emp_birthDate=2021-03-09&emp_passwd=23

Comment: You use `$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id_edit'];` the payload you put above just sets `emp_id`